# Using Request mixed Forms and Files with Annotation and optional fields

Tags: python, annotations, fastapi

I'd like to post mixed form fields and upload files to a FastAPI endpoint. The FastAPI documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/#__tabbed_2_2) states that you can mix params using `Annotated` and the `python-multipart` library e.g.

```py
@router.post("/upload")
async def upload_contents(
    an_int: Annotated[int, Form()],
    a_string: Annotated[str, Form()], 
    some_files: Annotated[list[UploadFile], File()]
):
```

However if I want to make posting of `a_string` optional, I have not found a way to make this work.

I have tried things like:

```py
@router.post("/upload")
async def upload_contents(
    an_int: Annotated[int, Form()],
    a_string: Annotated[Union[str, None], Form()], 
    some_files: Annotated[list[UploadFile], File()]
):
```

And also on @flakes suggestion:

```py
@router.post("/upload")
async def upload_contents(
    an_int: Annotated[int, Form()],
    a_string: Optional[Annotated[str], Form()]], 
    some_files: Annotated[list[UploadFile], File()]
):
```

While these run, the server is still requesting I provide the `a_string` parameter. Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Does this work? `Optional[Annotated[str, Form()]]`

Comment: @flakes unfortunately not, the code runs but still requiring the field

Answer (score 2):

It was discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/854).

Basically, if the default value is set in `Form()`, the parameter will be optional.

```py
@router.post("/upload")
async def upload_contents(
    an_int: Annotated[int, Form()],
    some_files: Annotated[List[UploadFile], File()],
    a_string: Union[str, None] = Form(default=None)
):
    return True
```

[image]

It seems that using `Annotated[Union[str, None], Form(default=None)]` isn't working and will return the following error

```bash
AssertionError: `Form` default value cannot be set in `Annotated` for 'a_string'. Set the default value with `=` instead.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works for me! Noting that the optional parameters need to be  positioned last